# Debian Bookworm on RPI-4 "who" command displays a large number instead of login date/time

Tags: debian

Using Debian Bookworm on RPI-4, the `who` command displays a large number instead of login date/time. Some searching suggested deleting and recreating `/run/utmp` and checking ownership and permissions.

I did change them from `root:root` and `rw-r--r--`  to  `root:utmp` and `rw-rw-r--` to match what is on other systems that work properly. None of that helped.

Here is the output from the `who` command:

```
root     pts/0        7205944946380205577 (192.168.0.100)
```

Should look like:

```
root     pts/0        2024-03-17 15:49 (192.168.0.100)
```

Two AMD processor systems work fine, the two RPI-4's don't.

I've investigated `who`:

```bash
type who
 who is hashed (/usr/bin/who)
who --version
 who (GNU coreutils) 9.1
```

My OS is Debian Bookworm 12.1 Kernel 6.1.21-v8+ aarch64

Comment: What date/time does the problematic Pi think it is, and is it correct?

Comment: Date/Time are accurate --> Tue Mar 26 10:11:19 AM MDT 2024

Comment: @02ebz06 you don't happen to have `gdb` installed on the Rpi? If you have (or want to spend the <150 MB installing it), could you try running `gdb /usr/bin/who`, and on the (gdb) shell then `start`, then `break strftime` (which is the function that formats times!) and then `continue`? You should get a line printed like `Breakpoint 2, __GI_strftime(…) at strftime.c`. **That** full line would be interesting!

Comment: gdb Is installed, output from commands you listed -->  Breakpoint 1 at 0xf7ec3804: file strftime.c, line 25.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I can't get that sequence to work. For me it's `gdb /usr/bin/who` then `break strftime` then `run`. On my Pi that returns `Breakpoint 1, __GI_strftime (s=0x2a19c "", maxsize=33, format=0x18e80 "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M",
tp=0x76fc4a2c <_tmbuf>) at strftime.c:25`

Comment: @ChrisDavies interesting; I typically `start` first, because that just means `break main; run` (followed by a removal of that breakpoint, in case main calls itself(?) ), i.e., it allows the dynamic loader to load all libraries, then when all the symbols are loaded, I set the breakpoints I need. Your result is how I expect it to be, however! That's good. The suspicion I have is that the `who` on OP's pi somehow hands a garbled `format` string to the `strftime`, or never calls that function. In the former case: huh; maybe storage corruption? In the latter case: broken libc upgrades??

Comment: Yes... I'm curious to see what happens too. I commented because their line looked like mine, and didn't include the `strftime()` you need

Comment: FYI - This is not just one system. It is on two RPI's so corruption unlikely. - If I do what Chris Davies did I get this output - Starting program: /usr/bin/who
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".
root     pts/0        7205944946380205577 (192.168.0.100)
[Inferior 1 (process 6631) exited normally] ----  Shows the number instead of date/time

Comment: I wish I could really tell you what is going on. But we can logically deduct where the data problem comes from – the utmp data as read is corrupted, according to `who`'s understanding of the data structure. Whether that is the fault of the writing end, the reading end, or gnulib source code versioning (or lack thereof): impossible to tell for me. See my answer. (esp. @ChrisDavies; this is all I could figure out. If you have any idea…)

Comment: Thanks for the time and effort you put into this Marcus, I really appreciate it.  I'd be lost looking at the code as I haven't done any C coding in decades and most OS and application code I've worked with in the past doesn't have comments.

Comment: Someone on the Raspberry Pi forum came up with a fix.  It was to install a newer version of who.  ---  wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/coreutils-9.4.tar.xz.  --- tar xvf coreutils-9.4.tar.xz.  ---  cd coreutils-9.4  ---  ./configure  ---  make  --- mv ./src/who  /bin

Answer (score 1):

OK, we're getting closer here.

Thanks to debugging with gdb, as you shown in your comment:

```
$> gdb /usr/bin/who
…
(gdb) break strftime
…
(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/bin/who [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".
 root pts/0 7205944946380205577 (192.168.0.100)
[Inferior 1 (process 6631) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

we can say that `strftime` doesn't actually get called – but it *should* get called, as far as `who`'s `src/who.c` version v9.1 is concerned (lines starting 330):

```c
/* Send properly parsed USER_PROCESS info to print_line.  The most
   recent boot time is BOOTTIME. */
static void
print_user (const STRUCT_UTMP *utmp_ent, time_t boottime)
{
// …
/* skipping to line 434 */
  print_line (sizeof UT_USER (utmp_ent), UT_USER (utmp_ent), mesg,
              sizeof utmp_ent->ut_line, utmp_ent->ut_line,
              time_string (utmp_ent), idlestr, pidstr,
              hoststr ? hoststr : "", "");
}
```

The interesting part here is the function `static char const *time_string(const STRUCT_UTMP *)`, being called here (lines 216ff), whose job it is to get the time info from the utmp entry and print it in a human-friendly manner

```c
/* Return a time string.  */
static char const *
time_string (const STRUCT_UTMP *utmp_ent)
{
  static char buf[INT_STRLEN_BOUND (intmax_t) + sizeof "-%m-%d %H:%M"];

  /* Don't take the address of UT_TIME_MEMBER directly.
     Ulrich Drepper wrote:
     "... GNU libc (and perhaps other libcs as well) have extended
     utmp file formats which do not use a simple time_t ut_time field.
     In glibc, ut_time is a macro which selects for backward compatibility
     the tv_sec member of a struct timeval value."  */
  time_t t = UT_TIME_MEMBER (utmp_ent);
  struct tm *tmp = localtime (&t);

  if (tmp)
    {
      strftime (buf, sizeof buf, time_format, tmp);
      return buf;
    }
  else
    return timetostr (t, buf);
}
```

Now, our debugger tells us `strftime` never gets called!

The only way that is possible is if `tmp` is `0`, i.e. when `localtime` returned `0`. Reading the glibc `localtime` man page, we learn that this can happen only in error conditions. Sadly, there's no indication what precisely goes wrong. But there's not too much that can actually go wrong converting a `time_t` to a local time stamp using `localtime` – the only specified error type is an overflow, when the value passed is just too large for human terms. And that's the case here:

When that error condition happens, a call to `timetostr` just calls `anytostr` (it's gnulib, specifically gnulib/lib/anytostr.c, please don't ask how to figure that out without grep or years of staring at gnulib code. The code is well-maintained at high effort, but honestly, it's terrible and macro-polluted C for historic reasons). `anytostr(inttype i, char *buf)` is honestly just a superfluous re-implementation of `sprintf(buf, "%jd")`, so what it does is just interpret the `time_t` from the utmp record as decimal number an print it!

Surprise, when reading your decimal number, 7205944946380205577, that's centuries to millenia in the future, even if it counts nanoseconds.

So, your utmp record is broken, hence `localtime` fails to convert it to a sensible local timestamp, and hence you are just printed the raw number.

Now, **why** your utmp record as read from the file is broken: I don't know.

That seems to be a serious bug in the two systems you run. Maybe the utmp record was written with a different definition of the struct than the libc uses that reads it in `who`? Maybe your file was copied from an x86 PC to an ARM machine (unlikely)?

That's why I speculated in the comments about a "broken libc update": One explanation would be that the `utmp.h` that `who` assumes is correct when it reads the utmp file differs from the one that was still assummed to be correct when the file was written. But you said you deleted that file, I assume you had logins afterwards, so we can rule that out.

At this point, this would really require debian-level debugging. I'd recommend filing a bug with the debian maintainers of `who` (probably the maintainers of the `coreutils` package. Ask them to make sure the gnulib of their coreutils is up to date, and that especially the configure scripts correctly detect the presence of `utmp.h` or `utmpx.h`. (refer them to this answer, by all means!). I have the suspicion that this is one of the many cases where the fact that gnulib is just a bunch of source code that you copy into your source code and that is hard to keep in lockstep with other system includes has bitten users.